# How to connect to the remote computer by providing Domian credentials using WMI connection in Python script

Tags: python-3.x

```
import wmi, time
ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xxx'
username = "XXXXXXX"
password = "XXXXXXX!"
SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
from socket import *
print "Establishing connection to %s" %ip
c = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
process_startup = c.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
process_startup.ShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL
process_id, result = c.Win32_Process.Create
 (CommandLine="Notepad.exe",ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)
if result == 0:
  print "Process started successfully: %d" % process_id
else:
  raise RuntimeError, "Problem creating process: %d" % result
```

**Please help: How to connect with domain credentials as my system is under domain**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to specify either the "machinename" or "domainname" as a prefix to the user name. Here is an [example](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html#connecting-to-a-remote-machine-as-a-named-user) of specifying machnename as a prefix to the username. Same example goes for domain.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to connect to the computer successfully **but the problem I am facing now is process is not interactive. I could c the proces"Notepad.exe" is running in task manager but not interactive(visible:notepad not launched) **